# Diferrence between First() and Key in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I did 2 functions which return a unique number from array used LINQ (they're almost the same)

```
public static int GetUnique(IEnumerable<int> numbers) =>
        numbers.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).First().Key;

public static int GetUnique2(IEnumerable<int> numbers) =>
        numbers.GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() == 1).First().First();
```

using both of them I've got good output

```
Console.WriteLine(TestClass.GetUnique(new[] { 10, 10, 7, 10 }));        //7
Console.WriteLine(TestClass.GetUnique2(new[] { 10, 10, 7, 10 }));       //7
Console.WriteLine(TestClass.GetUnique(new[] { 5, 5, 5, -5 }));          //-5
Console.WriteLine(TestClass.GetUnique2(new[] { 5, 5, 5, -5 }));         //-5
Console.WriteLine(TestClass.GetUnique(new[] { 21, 21, 14, 21, 21 }));   //14
Console.WriteLine(TestClass.GetUnique2(new[] { 21, 21, 14, 21, 21 }));  //14
```

can you explain me what's the difference between First() and Key?

Comment: Since, you are working on collection of **int** that's why you are seeing the same observation. If you run the same query on a collection of any **object** then you will notice the difference

Comment: Key is the item you grouped by. First is the first item of a collection

Comment: As a side note to the above, only use First() if you know that you're not going to get a null response, use FirstOrDefault() if you might get a null back

Comment: It's because your key is the same as the items you are grouping.  The resulting groups are going to contain one value that is equal to the `Key`.

Comment: @Coffee `FirstOrDefault` is for when you might get an empty collection.  That would still throw if the collection is `null`.  So it could be `.FirstOrDefault()?.First()` since the filter might result in no results or the original source might be empty, but if there are any resulting groups that will not be empty (but now the null conditional operator is needed)

Comment: A groupby give a double array    key[]<List<Value>>.  So Key gets the key name while First() get the index zero of the list and returns the value.  In your case the List has only one object (the number) so the the key and the value are the same.

Comment: @jdweng Actually the result is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` where `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>` is an `IEnumerable<TSource>` and has a `TKey` `Key` property.